# Siempre obtengo el mismo registro dentro de una lista

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Al intentar obtener todos los artículos de la pagina consultada solo obtengo el primer registro tantas veces artículos hayan en la URL consultada.

```
class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mercado'
    allowed_domain = ['www.mercadolibre.com.ar']
    start_urls = ['https://videojuegos.mercadolibre.com.ar/videojuegos/ps4/fisico/_DisplayType_LF_PriceRange_1200-2500']


    def parse(self, response):
            for articulo in response.xpath('//li[@class="ui-search-layout__item"]'):
                
                precio= articulo.xpath('//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]//text()').get()
                titulo= articulo.xpath('//h2[@class="ui-search-item__title"]//text()').get()
                
                yield {
                        'price': precio,
                        'title': titulo
                     }
```

Así se vería la salida a modo de ejemplo

```json
[ 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}, 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}, 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}, 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"},  
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}, 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}, 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}, 
  {"price": "2.099", "title": "Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 F\u00edsico"}
]
```

Gracias.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que la expresión `xpath()` que usas dentro del bucle contiene una ruta absoluta. Es decir, aquí por ejemplo:

```py
  precio= articulo.xpath('//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]//text()').get()
```

Aunque `articulo` es un elemento particular, al ejecutar sobre él `.xpath()` puedes pasarle una ruta absoluta o relativa. Si se la pasas absoluta (que comience por `/`) se aplicará desde la raíz del documento, en vez de desde ese elemento.

Cambialo por una ruta relativa, así:

```py
            for articulo in response.xpath('//li[@class="ui-search-layout__item"]'):
               precio= articulo.xpath('.//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]//text()').get()
               titulo= articulo.xpath('.//h2[@class="ui-search-item__title"]//text()').get()
```

Ahora el resultado será:

```json
{'price': '2.099', 'title': 'Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 2 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 Físico'}
{'price': '1.399', 'title': 'FIFA 19 Standard Edition Electronic Arts PS4 Físico'}
{'price': '3.199', 'title': 'Gran Turismo Sport Standard Edition Sony PS4 Físico'}
// ... omitidos ...
{'price': '2.077', 'title': 'Juego Ps4 Shadow Of War Middle Earth Oferta Navidad'}
{'price': '1.799', 'title': 'Metal Gear Survive Juego Ps4 Fisico/ Mipowerdestiny'}
```